# Count DIVs with specific class where class name is a variable

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have some problem with this code...

```
$("select#kronologia option").each(function() {
    var classname=$(this).val();
    alert($("article."+classname).length);
});
```

Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: article.

I want to count divs with specific class where the class name comes from a select field. I got syntax error. See above...

If i change this line

```
var classname=$(this).val();
```

to this

```
var classname="2013";
```

the script is OK.

Any help would be great...

Comment: I've created a simple JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/myae5438/. Your code seems to be correct, are you sure this piece or code created the problem? Can you show your HTML as well?

Comment: OK, you are right.

My code is inside an onchange, maybe theres the problem. I modified the fiddle, could you check it please?

https://jsfiddle.net/myae5438/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the updated [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/myae5438/4/).

The problem is that your first value is empty, therefore jquery will try to find elements matching `article.` (empty option value), that is indeed an incorrect expression. As you can see in the fiddle, when the value is empty it's skipped and your script will work. Ofcourse you can alter the behaviour of an empty value to your own needs.

```
$('select#kronologia').on('change', function(e) {
    $(this).find('option').each(function() {
        var classname = $(this).val();

        if (classname === '') {
            return true;
        }

        alert($('article.'+classname).length);
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This is correct! You saved my day! :)

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `var classname=$(this).val();` to `var classname=str($(this).val());`

Answer (score 0):

what is article there? Is it a class prefix or id prefix

```
$("select#kronologia option").each(function() {
    var classname=$(this).val();
    alert($(".article"+classname).length);
});
```

or

```
$("select#kronologia option").each(function() {
    var classname=$(this).val();
    alert($("#article"+classname).length);
});
```

Comment: Article is not a class or ID ...It's a html5 element <article> 
And i would like to count <article class="2013">

Answer (score 0):

When you search for Class using JQuery there should be prefix "." a basic rule.
You have done everything fine just  append prefix for searching with class name as below.

```
alert($(".article"+classname).length);
```

https://codepen.io/JayPatel758/pen/wdpavo

Comment: Article is not a class or ID ...It's a html5 element <article> 
And i would like to count <article class="2013">